# Android MapFragment resizing animation choppy/lagging

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently working on resizing an Google Map MapFragment view (from a fullscreen height to half screen). I used a ValueAnimator to achieve this, however the animation is seems to be lagging on the device (Nexus 6p). I am using all the default interpolator. What did I do wrong ?

```
var animY = ValueAnimator.OfFloat(startY, endY);
animY.SetDuration(1000);
animY.AddUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdatedListener((a) =>
    {
        var layout = MapFragment.View.LayoutParameters;
        layout.Height = (int)a.AnimatedValue;
        MapFragment.View.LayoutParameters = layout;
        MapFragment.View.RequestLayout();
    }));
animY.Start();
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I assume it happens because you should not change the `SupportMapFragment` size, but instead maybe cover part of it and and move the camera accordingly. If you found any solution please add the answer.

Answer (score -1):

hey just set the initial size of the mapView or mapFragment to the size you want it to expand to and then put it in a holder layout that's smaller (the initial size of map you wanted) and when you want to animate , just animate the holder view. the lagging happens because of time consumption of redrawing the map.